# Which comics cover the origin of the many Hulks and S.M.A.S.H.?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I haven't read a Hulk storyline since Planet Hulk and Word War Hulk, and I'd like to start reading Hulk comics again.

If it helps, there's a Marvel animated feature called *Hulk and the Agents of S.M.A.S.H.*, which is what inspired the question. I don't know if this is just a cartoon creation, or if it's based on the comics.

So, if S.M.A.S.H. is something in the comics, I'd be primarily interested in the origins and arcs that lead up to S.M.A.S.H. being established.

Otherwise, what comics/graphic novels do I need to read to get caught up on the origin and important arcs for the following characters:

- Post-Word War Hulk Hulk (No origin necessary)
- Red Hulk
- Skaar
- A-Bomb
- She-Hulk (No origin necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animated [**Hulk and the Agents of S.M.A.S.H.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_and_the_Agents_of_S.M.A.S.H.) is not based on any particular story arc or team within the comics. Rather, it appears to be more of an attempt to bring the Hulk-related characters into their own show. That said, the overall concept IS based on several attempts within the comics by both the [US military](http://marvel.wikia.com/Hulkbusters_(US_Military)_(Earth-616)) and [S.H.I.E.L.D.](http://marvel.wikia.com/S.H.I.E.L.D.) to recruit and/or control Gamma-based characters.

[image]

Rather than list what arcs or comics to read, I'll instead direct you to the [Marvel.Com](http://marvel.com/universe/Main_Page) wiki page for each character. Each page includes a full biography & history of the character, as well as listing what comic they debuted in. From left to right in the image above, we have:

- [Skaar](http://marvel.com/universe/Skaar)

  > Hulk's son from his time on Sakaar during the "Planet Hulk" arc. Although Hulk did not originally know of Skaar, the two eventually met following the events of "World War Hulk". An angry Skaar blames Hulk for Sakaar's destruction, and the two butt heads a lot
- [She-Hulk](http://marvel.com/universe/She-Hulk)

  > Jennifer Walters, Hulk's cousin who became She-Hulk after receiving a blood donation from Bruce Banner that saved her life. Originally a lawyer, she has also worked as a SHIELD agent, yet has always been one of Hulk's staunchest supporters
- [The Incredible Hulk](http://marvel.com/universe/Hulk_(Bruce_Banner))

  > Bruce Banner became The Incredible Hulk as the result of a freak accident involving Gamma radiation. He has since become a wanted fugitive by the government despite his attempts protect the innocent and be a hero
- [The Red Hulk](http://marvel.com/universe/Red_Hulk)

  > General "Thunderbolt" Ross attempted to capture The Hulk for years. After the results of the "World War Hulk" arc, an exasperated Ross volunteered to become The Red Hulk in hopes that he could finally defeat his long-time nemesis
- [A-Bomb](http://marvel.com/universe/Jones,_Rick)

  > The perpetual side-kick, Rick Jones only wanted to be a hero, yet always seemed to have the worst luck... even getting cancer from his time around The Hulk. Jones was transformed by A.I.M into a blue replacement for The Abomination, albeit he became a dim-witted monstrosity that calls itself "A-Bomb" instead

Obviously, these pages will contain major spoilers for each character. Additional information can be found on the [Unofficial Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Main_Page), which is more likely to list individual comic issues for arcs.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason I've avoided the Wiki is because I want to avoid those spoilers.

Comment: @CreationEdge : not sure how well you'll be able to avoid spoilers, but I've added a brief origin to each character under spoiler tags. Hopefully that will tell you what you want with minimal spoilers.

Comment: I also watch AoS too (with my kid) and was a massive Hulk reader during the Planet Hulk and WWH time and just past Fear itself. Recently wondered into a comic shop to see what was good, although it is not AoS, the rest of the Disney XD: Marvel Universe has started getting there own titles, Spiderman and Avengers and I myself and hopeful Aos will receive a title series too based on its popularity amongst the younger crowd. My boy loves Devil Dino and A bomb. From my understanding these books are extra 'episodes'.